# java mysql connection link failure

Tags: java, mysql, sockets, buffer

After run well for 34 nodes.. my program get some message error looks like this :

```
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure
The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. 
The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor8.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance
                      (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2260)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.<init>(ConnectionImpl.java:787)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.JDBC4Connection.<init>(JDBC4Connection.java:49)
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor4.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(
                       DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.getInstance(ConnectionImpl.java:357)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:285)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:582)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:207)
        at org.sc.timetable.core.Database.Koneksi2DBMS(Database.java:77)
        at org.sc.timetable.core.Node.jumlahNode(Node.java:55)
        at org.sc.timetable.core.Node.DataPemetaan(Node.java:73)
        at org.sc.timetable.core.Node.matriknode(Node.java:123)
        at org.sc.timetable.core.Node.main(Node.java:158)

Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.CommunicationsException: Communications link failure

The last packet sent successfully to the server was 0 milliseconds ago. The driver has not received any packets from the server.
        at sun.reflect.GeneratedConstructorAccessor8.newInstance(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance
                      (DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:27)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:513)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:409)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createCommunicationsException(SQLError.java:1122)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:344)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.createNewIO(ConnectionImpl.java:2181)
        ... 15 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: No buffer space available (maximum connections reached?): connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:351)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:213)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:200)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:218)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.StandardSocketFactory.connect(StandardSocketFactory.java:256)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.<init>(MysqlIO.java:293)
        ... 16 more
```

Java Result: 1

Can somebody help me?

Comment: I had some problem on Windows 7. 
I solved it by https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/196271

Answer (score 0):

See the following links,

https://serverfault.com/questions/89955/unable-to-connect-to-mysql-through-jdbc-connector-through-tomcat-or-externally

http://forums.mysql.com/read.php?39,199085,388953#msg-388953

http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35353

Mostly it talks about the version of the driver. Please check.